# Is it possible to store this number as a floating point with these restrictions?

Tags: floating-point

So I'm looking at a question that asks me to represent 16.875 as a 10 bit floating point number with 1 sign bit, 3 exponent bits, and 6 mantissa bits. However, I am questioning whether this is possible in base 2(binary). This is because 16 = 10000 in binary which means that I would have to multiply by 2^4 to obtain this number. However, since there are only 3 exponent bits, isn't the largest possible exponent 3, since if I use all ones it will be 7-3(the bias)=4 but then it will be a NaN, so the largest normal number can only use up to the exponent 3. I am really confused as to whether this question is incorrect or if my logic/knowledge is incorrect.

Comment: Since the format has 3 exponent bits and 6 significand bits (“signifcand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion; a mantissa is the fraction portion of a logarithm), it is not a standard format. If it is not a standard format, who says you have to use any sort of standard pattern for the exponent bias or for the meaning of an all-ones exponent. Define them as suits your needs.